# Is calling Java's Calendar.getTime() necessary to update the object?

Tags: java, calendar

I came across a comment in some java code that states that `getTime()` needs to be called to update the `Calendar` object. Is this true? I cannot find anything that says that this is necessary.

Here's the code:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
cal.set(2009, 9 - 1, 10, 2, 30);
// Get Time needs to be called to update the Calendar object
cal.getTime();
```

Comment: also, just to make your code more concise, you should use this version of the constructor: GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) .... none of the other calls are really needed.

Comment: Please, Check my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Comment: Did it use to be in some prior version of java?

Comment: No, never. Existing behaviour is never changed in that way.

Comment: Were that true, it would be a good example of terribly designed API.

Getter methods should be read only (this is when I miss the const modifier from C++).

Comment: @abahgat - I agree which is why I questioned it. The developer also didn't assign the result to anything. They just used it as if it didn't return anything.

Comment: @abahgat: `java.util.Calendar` *is* a terribly designed API

Comment: At least on getter must be called to update the properties of the instance. That is how they designed calendar

Answer (score 12):

`cal.getTime()` does indeed need to be called to re-calculate its internals. It is very strange behavior for the API but the [Calendar javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) state this explicitly:

> **Getting and Setting Calendar Field Values**
>
> The calendar field values can be set by calling the set methods. Any
>   field values set in a Calendar will not be interpreted until it needs
>   to calculate its time value (milliseconds from the Epoch) or values of
>   the calendar fields. Calling the get, getTimeInMillis, getTime, add
>   and roll involves such calculation.

...

> **Field Manipulation**
>
> The calendar fields can be changed using three methods: set(), add(),
>   and roll(). set(f, value) changes calendar field f to value. In
>   addition, it sets an internal member variable to indicate that
>   calendar field f has been changed. Although calendar field f is
>   changed immediately, the calendar's time value in milliseconds is not
>   recomputed until the next call to get(), getTime(), getTimeInMillis(),
>   add(), or roll() is made. Thus, multiple calls to set() do not trigger
>   multiple, unnecessary computations. As a result of changing a calendar
>   field using set(), other calendar fields may also change, depending on
>   the calendar field, the calendar field value, and the calendar system.
>   In addition, get(f) will not necessarily return value set by the call
>   to the set method after the calendar fields have been recomputed. The
>   specifics are determined by the concrete calendar class.

The behavior is unexpected and does not always occur but the following unit tests should exemplify this behavior and always occur.

```
/**
 * Fails the assertion due to missing getTime()
 * @throws ParseException 
 */
public class DateTest {

    @Test
    public void testNoGetTime() throws ParseException {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date testDate = df.parse("04/15/2013");
        Calendar testCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        testCal.setTime(testDate);
        Date expectedDate = df.parse("04/04/2013");
        Date actualDate = null;

        testCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, testCal.getMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        //testCal.getTime();
        testCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
        testCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        actualDate = testCal.getTime();
        assertEquals("Dates should be equal", expectedDate.toString(), actualDate.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithGetTime() throws ParseException {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date testDate = df.parse("04/15/2013");
        Calendar testCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        testCal.setTime(testDate);
        Date expectedDate = df.parse("04/04/2013");
        Date actualDate = null;

        testCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, testCal.getMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        testCal.getTime();
        testCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
        testCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        actualDate = testCal.getTime();
        assertEquals("Dates should be equal", expectedDate.toString(), actualDate.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: In short words: If you set the same fields multiple times, for example by setTime(..) and set(Day of week) then you should trigger a recalculate between using getTime() or you will have some strange effect.

Answer (score 3):

@skaffman Answer is **NOT CORRECT**.

Here is an example which proves what I am saying.

```
//Create an Calendar object set to todays date & time
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Log.d(Tag, "Now : "+ calendar.toString());

//Set the Calendar to the first day of Month
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
Log.d(Tag, "Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1: "+ calendar.toString());
```

This is the Log.d output:

```
Now : java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1478834995641,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=America/Chicago,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=46,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=10,DAY_OF_YEAR=315,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=21,MINUTE=29,SECOND=55,MILLISECOND=641,ZONE_OFFSET=-21600000,DST_OFFSET=0] Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1: 
Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=America/Chicago,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=46,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=315,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=21,MINUTE=29,SECOND=55,MILLISECOND=641,ZONE_OFFSET=-21600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

If you take time to check it: 
The calendar at the beginning shows:

```
time=1478834995641
DAY_OF_MONTH=10  
DAY_OF_YEAR=315
```

However, when you set it to the first day of the month:

```
time=?
DAY_OF_MONTH=1  
DAY_OF_YEAR=315
```

Yes, it changed the first day of the month as we wanted, nevertheless some attributes remain the same. For instance, how it comes we set the calendar to `DAY_OF_MONTH=1` but we are still in `DAY_OF_YEAR=315`.

If we use any of the following functions, it will force the Calendar to update.

> Calling the get, getTimeInMillis, getTime, add and roll.

From the Calendar Class in Javadocs Check :[Getting and Setting Calendar Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

To fix it, we add the following code `calendar.getTimeInMillis();` which forces the Calendar to update its attributes.

```
//Create an Calendar object set to todays date & time
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Log.d(Tag, "Now : "+ calendar.toString());

//Set the Calendar to the first day of Month
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
//UPDATE BY CALLING getTimeInMillis() or any of the previously mentioned functions
calendar.getTimeInMillis();
Log.d(Tag, "Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1: "+ calendar.toString());
```

Now, lets Check Results:

```
Now : java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1478836452183,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=America/Chicago,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=46,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=10,DAY_OF_YEAR=315,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=21,MINUTE=54,SECOND=12,MILLISECOND=183,ZONE_OFFSET=-21600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1478055252183,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=America/Chicago,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=45,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=306,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=21,MINUTE=54,SECOND=12,MILLISECOND=183,ZONE_OFFSET=-21600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

Therefore, @skaffman Answer is not correct, as for your question `Calendar.getTime();` indeed is needed if you do not want to get weird values at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You could be hitting [Bug ID 4851640](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4851640)

> Calling get(...) / getTime() on a Calendar instance makes isSet(...) useless!

Comment: @eed3si9n - good find - I don't think we are using isSet but I will look again.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not be necessary.

Was the Calendar serialized immediate afterwards?

I've been caught by a bug with Calendar serialization in older jvms.

[Bug parade bug #4328747](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4328747)

Calling getTime before serialization may be enough to get around the bug, although I don't have a sufficiently old JVM installed for me to confirm that.

Comment: No it wasn't. The workaround for the bug isn't to call getTime() but rather get/setGregorianChange(). I was thinking that this may have been a bug a long time ago (this is older code I'm looking at) but it appears as if that isn't the case.

Comment: There were actually several different workarounds that worked, getGregorianChange was one of them, but getTime may have been another of them.

anyways, its irrelevant if was wasn't serialized anyways