# Android Calendar getFirstDayOfWeek bug

Tags: java, android, java-calendar

I want to get the first day of the week but I have a strange bug.
If I use this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2017, 0, 1);

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.getDefault());
Log.d(TAG, "Date: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

My log displays the wrong date: `D/Activity: Date: lundi 2 janvier 2017`

But if I use the `getTime()` method just like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2017, 0, 1);
cal.getTime(); // Here

cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.getDefault());
Log.d(TAG, "Date: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

My log display the correct date: `D/Activity: Date: lundi 26 décembre 2016`

My phone uses the French language so my week begins on Monday.

Somebody knows why?

Comment: Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` etc.) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67577875/10819573) based on the modern date-time API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's Calendar API is infamous for its behavior regarding updating fields. The problem is that multiple `set()` calls may lead to some unexpected result because some internals don't get adjusted properly, i.e. it doesn't update some values until it really has to, e.g. when you call `getTime()`.

You can read more on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19233970/559745).

So, the fix for this issue is indeed to call `getTime()` or `getTimeInMillis()` in between.